# How to calculate the extent of a projection?

Tags: coordinate-system, openstreetmap, openlayers, extents

I am trying to change the projection of my Open Layers map from 'EPSG:3857' to 'EPSG:26915'. I tried to use

```
var projection=new ol.proj.Projection({
    code: 'EPSG: 26915',
    extent:extent_projection,
    units: 'm'
  });

  var  view =new ol.View({
         projection: projection,
         center: [-57685.58, 4615858.09],
         zoom: 2
        });
```

The map looks extremely blurry. I believe that I need correct extent_projection to remove the blurriness of my openLayers map. I tried going to www.epsg.io and used projected bounds of EPSG:26915 for my extent array. However, it didn't change anything. The following is the image of my blurry map. I need to correct the center and extent of my map. How can I get the extent for my projection?

[image: The image describes the blurry map and incorrectly positioned raster]

Comment: check this post -->http://freeopengis.blogspot.gr/2017/04/open-layers-3-playing-with-projections.html.(case2 - subcase2) You need to include pro4js library in order to use local projections

Comment: I know but that's my question how do we know what is the correct extent for EPSG:26915 projection. In subcase2), how do they know the extent of var 2100extent ?

Comment: http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/26915/